# C++ : Unable to print the text formatted as expected

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print this LIST but it's driving me insane.

So this is the output that I wanted to get :

```
Veranstaltungen:
1: Freitag     08:00 - 09:30   SU Informatik III     Kevin Kaufmann  H3
2: Freitag     10:00 - 11:30   Ueb Informatik III    Kevin Kaufmann  D 114
3: Freitag     12:15 - 13:45   Ueb Informatik III    Kevin Kaufmann  D 114
4: Montag      10:00 - 11:30   SU Mathe III          Nathan Neuling  B 301
5: Mittwoch    10:00 - 11:30   Ueb Mathe III         Nathan Neuling  D 209
6: Donnerstag  16:00 - 17:30   Englisch              Sabine Sauber   D 419
7: Dienstag    16:00 - 17:30   SU Digitale Systeme   Willi Witzig    H5
8: Dienstag    17:45 - 19:15   Ueb Digitale Systeme  Willi Witzig    D 114
```

This is the print function in my code :

I tried first of all this simple alternative here:

```
void CEvents::print()
    {
      cout << "Veranstaltungen:" << endl ;
    
      for (int i = 0 ; i < counter;i++)
      {
        CWeekday Day = Events[i]->WeekDay;
        cout<<i+1<<": "<<Events[i]->getDay(Day) << "        ";
        Events[i]->Block->print();
        cout<<"     "<<Events[i]->Name<<"     "<<Events[i]->Teacher->Name<<"     "<<Events[i]->Room->Name<< endl;
      }
    
    
    }
```

I got from this code this output :

```
Veranstaltungen:
1: Freitag        08:00 - 09:30     SU Informatik III      Kevin Kaufmann     H3
2: Freitag        10:00 - 11:30     Ueb Informatik III      Kevin Kaufmann     D 114
3: Freitag        12:15 - 13:45     Ueb Informatik III      Kevin Kaufmann     D 114
4: Montag        10:00 - 11:30     SU Mathe III      Nathan Neuling     B 301
5: Mittwoch        10:00 - 11:30     Ueb Mathe III      Nathan Neuling     D 209
6: Donnerstag        16:00 - 17:30     Englisch      Sabine Sauber      D 419
7: Dienstag        16:00 - 17:30     SU Digitale Systeme      Willi Witzig      H5
8: Dienstag        17:45 - 19:15     Ueb Digitale Systeme     Willi Witzig      D 114
```

Of course this one won't work correctly because they all don't have the same lengths but atleast the first part here is correct  .

Then I tried to switch to printf() instead of cout , got a little closer to the result but still not the same :

```
extern "C" void CEvents::print()
{
  cout << "Veranstaltungen:" << endl ;
  string a= " ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < counter;i++)
  {
    CWeekday Day = Events[i]->WeekDay;
    printf("%d: %10s %5s",i+1,Events[i]->getDay(Day).c_str(),a.c_str());
    Events[i]->Block->print(); 
    printf("%30s %20s %10s\n",Events[i]->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Teacher->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Room->Name.c_str());
   }

}
```

For this code I got this output :

```
1:    Freitag      08:00 - 09:30            SU Informatik III        Kevin Kaufmann        H3
2:    Freitag      10:00 - 11:30           Ueb Informatik III        Kevin Kaufmann      D 114
3:    Freitag      12:15 - 13:45           Ueb Informatik III        Kevin Kaufmann      D 114
4:     Montag      10:00 - 11:30                 SU Mathe III        Nathan Neuling      B 301
5:   Mittwoch      10:00 - 11:30                Ueb Mathe III        Nathan Neuling      D 209
6: Donnerstag      16:00 - 17:30                     Englisch        Sabine Sauber       D 419
7:   Dienstag      16:00 - 17:30          SU Digitale Systeme         Willi Witzig         H5
8:   Dienstag      17:45 - 19:15          Ueb Digitale Systeme        Willi Witzig       D 114
```

Now second part is correct(the time) and the other parts are not.
How do I make this format correctly ?

Comment: Could you please post the desired output as text, similar to how you post your actual output as text?

Comment: You *know* you can set field widths in C++ using [standard manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)? Haven't your text-book (or tutorial or class) ever mentioned them?

Comment: @some obviously they did not know that. But now they do. Gaston, dude's link is the canonical way to set output text width and alignment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know but I still didn't check them yet . Still this is not the problem .

Comment: "Still this is not the problem ." Please explain. In the question. By [edit]ing it.

Comment: Your `printf` call that you show is using field width exclusively to format the output, and you claim that it works. Why wouldn't the same work when using `std::cout` and `std::setw`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you seem to misunderstand what `extern "C"` means. It doesn't mean you can call "C" functions from your C++ code, and in fact is totally useless for member functions.

Comment: @Yunnosch the problem is not about knowing how to set field widths in C++ . It's about knowing how to print the desired output .

Comment: To fix your problems you need to left justify the text for some fields (`printf("%-30s %-20s %-10s\n",Events[i]->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Teacher->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Room->Name.c_str());` note the minus in the number before `s`. Additionally I think you will have to make some of the fields wider than this constants

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thank you. The minus fixed the problem.

Comment: Consider creating an answer please. I would like this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problems you need to left justify the text for some fields:

```
printf("%-30s %-20s %-10s\n",Events[i]->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Teacher->Name.c_str(),Events[i]->Room->Name.c_str();
```

Note the minus in the number before s. Additionally I think you will have to make some of the fields wider than this constants

Answer (score 3):

Using [`std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) should get you the formatting you want.

I've had to improvise a little as you didn't provide a full example but you should be able to adapt this code into yours:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 5>> data =
    {
        { "Freitag", "08:00 - 09:30", "SU Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "H3" },
        { "Freitag", "10:00 - 11:30", "Ueb Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "D 114" },
        { "Freitag", "12:15 - 13:45", "Ueb Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "D 114" },
        { "Montag", "10:00 - 11:30", "SU Mathe III", "Nathan Neuling", "B 301" },
        { "Mittwoch", "10:00 - 11:30", "Ueb Mathe III", "Nathan Neuling", "D 209" },
        { "Donnerstag", "16:00 - 17:30", "Englisch", "Sabine Sauber", "D 419" },
        { "Dienstag", "16:00 - 17:30", "SU Digitale Systeme", "Willi Witzig", "H5" },
        { "Dienstag", "17:45 - 19:15", "Ueb Digitale Systeme", "Willi Witzig", "D 114" },
    };
    std::cout << "Veranstaltungen:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << (i+1) << ": " <<
            std::left <<
            std::setw(12) << data[i][0] <<
            std::setw(16) << data[i][1] <<
            std::setw(22) << data[i][2] <<
            std::setw(16) << data[i][3] <<
            data[i][4] << "\n";
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EqafWs

Answer (score 1):

As a side note here is [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ranges-api) example (note `fmt` is part of C++20 and currently is not supported by any compiler, so it has to be used as external library):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 5>> data =
    {
        { "Freitag", "08:00 - 09:30", "SU Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "H3" },
        { "Freitag", "10:00 - 11:30", "Ueb Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "D 114" },
        { "Freitag", "12:15 - 13:45", "Ueb Informatik III", "Kevin Kaufmann", "D 114" },
        { "Montag", "10:00 - 11:30", "SU Mathe III", "Nathan Neuling", "B 301" },
        { "Mittwoch", "10:00 - 11:30", "Ueb Mathe III", "Nathan Neuling", "D 209" },
        { "Donnerstag", "16:00 - 17:30", "Englisch", "Sabine Sauber", "D 419" },
        { "Dienstag", "16:00 - 17:30", "SU Digitale Systeme", "Willi Witzig", "H5" },
        { "Dienstag", "17:45 - 19:15", "Ueb Digitale Systeme", "Willi Witzig", "D 114" },
    };
    std::cout << "Veranstaltungen:\n";
    size_t i = 0;
    for (const auto&x : data)
    {
        fmt::print("{:2}: {:12} {:16} {:22} {:16} {}\n",
                   ++i, x[0], x[1],  x[2], x[3], x[4]);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9PTrvb)